# retrieve data from firebase using Fragment class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my class extends Fragment (im using a tabbed activity), below code is in onCreate() method. But when I try to run, my app crashes. Is it not possible to retrieve data from firebase using Fragment extended class? Or as I've read from other questions it says that i should use RecyclerView. Please advise.

```
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //check type if student
                no = Integer.parseInt(ds.child("name").getValue().toString());
                driverName = ds.child("id").getValue().toString();
                route = ds.child("mother").getValue().toString();
                String schedule1 = ds.child("father").getValue().toString();
                status = ds.child("status").getValue().toString();
                user.put(Integer.parseInt(ds.getKey().toString()), new User(name, id, father, mother, status));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w("LogFragment", "loadLog:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why does it crash, what is the error in the logcat?

Comment: found it, the field name doesn't reflect the one in firebase. thanks

Comment: @PeterHaddad, do u know why my user (hashmap) when used by onCreateView there's no data found. We have tried logging the user using a loop in onCreate and it has values. But when called in onCreateView list is empty